# How to grab the values of objects within objects

Tags: javascript, object

I'm given an object, which has names of individuals as keys and the value of those keys is an object containing their favorite movies and the ratings they would give them. I am trying compile all the movie titles into an object along with their total score from each individual.

```
userRatings = {
   "Ryan" => {"Avengers" => 8, "Little Mermaid" => 8, "Inception" => 
9},
   "Clay" => {"Avengers" => 9, "Inception" => 10, "Independence Day" 
=> 7},
   "Christine" => {"Avengers" => 9, "Little Mermaid" => 8, 
"Inception" => 7},
   "Jon" => {"Avengers" => 5, "Little Mermaid" => 2, "Inception" => 
8},
   "David" => {"Avengers" => 3, "Inception" => 8, "Independence Day" 
=> 6}
}

function averageMovieRatings(obj) {
  var ratingObj = {};

  for (var k in obj) {
    var name = obj[key];

    for (var j in name) {
      if (ratingObj[j] === undefined) {
        ratingObj[j] = name[j];
      } else {
        ratingObj[j] += name[j];
      }
    }
  }
  return ratingObj;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - retrieve value from nested object, using array of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590743/javascript-retrieve-value-from-nested-object-using-array-of-keys)

Comment: You seem to be mixing PHP and JavaScript syntax. JS uses `key: value`, not `key => value`.

Comment: The function looks fine, though. What problem are you having?

Comment: Why is the function named `average` when it actually calculates a total? Do you need it to calculate average instead? Then you need to store the counts as well as totals, so you can calculate `total / count` for each movie.

Answer (score 0):

You need valid JSON

```
var userRatings = {
    "Ryan": {
        "Avengers": 8,
        "Little Mermaid": 8,
        "Inception": 9
    },
    "Clay": {
        "Avengers": 9,
        "Inception": 10,
        "Independence Day": 7
    },
    "Christine": {
        "Avengers": 9,
        "Little Mermaid": 8,
        "Inception": 7
    },
    "Jon": {
        "Avengers": 5,
        "Little Mermaid": 2,
        "Inception": 8
    },
    "David": {
        "Avengers": 3,
        "Inception": 8,
        "Independence Day": 6
    }

}
```

In your function code change [key] to [k]

```
function averageMovieRatings(obj) {
  var ratingObj = {};

  for (var k in obj) {
    var name = obj[k];

    for (var j in name) {
      if (ratingObj[j] === undefined) {
        ratingObj[j] = name[j];
      } else {
        ratingObj[j] += name[j];
      }
    }
  }
  return ratingObj;
}
averageMovieRatings(userRatings);
```

You should get this object as your result

```
{
    "Avengers": 34,
    "Inception": 42,
    "Independence Day": 13,
    "Little Mermaid": 18
}
```