# How to replace nested objects in a TypeScript object

Tags: typescript

What I need to do is modify a TypeScript object by doing a key search (the key can be repeated, so I need to check that it belongs to the right branch) and modifying the corresponding object. In short if this is the object:

```js
{
   requirements: {
     general_info: {
       aircraft: {
         payload: { '@_unit': 'kg' },
         autopilot_ratio: '',
       },
       power: {
         number_of_engines: '',
       },
       geometrical: {
         payload: { '@_unit': 'kg' },
         design_approach: { target: '' },
       },
     },
   },
}
```

must be transformed into:

```js
{
   requirements: {
     general_info: {
       aircraft: {
         payload: { '@_unit': 'hg', '#text': 3000},
         autopilot_ratio: '',
       },
       power: {
         number_of_engines: '',
       },
       geometrical: {
         payload: { '@_unit': 'kg' },
         design_approach: { target: '' },
       },
     },
   },
}
```

I understand that it has to be a recursive function. I tried to write the following function but I don't know how to prevent nested objects from being inserted multiple times

```js
const updateObject = (json: any, searchKey: string, unit: string, value: number): Object => {
  return Object.keys(json).map((key: string) => {
    if (key !== searchKey && typeof json[key] !== 'string') {
      return updateObject(json[key], searchKey, unit, value);
    } else {
      if (typeof json[key] !== 'string') {
        json[key]['@_unit'] = unit;
        json[key]['#text'] = value;
        return json;
      } else {
        return json;
      }
    }
  });
};

console.dir(updateObject(json, 'payload', 'hg', 3000), { depth: null });
```

Among other things, this changes all the payload instances, it would also be useful to pass `requirements.general_info.aircraft.payload` as searchKey so as to change only the desired one

**EDIT**
The object `{ '@_unit': 'kg' }` has a fixed format and I can already know a priori that it will be `{ '@_unit': 'hg', '#text': 3000}` the problem is but replace it in the right place of the JSON because it is not unique, otherwise a JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json).replace() would have been enough.

Comment: *"I understand that it has to be a recursive function..."* Does it? In your example, `payload` only appears at a single *level* in the object tree (as a child of a child of a child of `requirements`). You don't need a recursive function if that's the case.

Comment: You're probably right, it's the only way I've found to cycle through nested objects

Comment: If you already have the path to the object to update (ie `requirements.general_info.aircraft.payload`) you could use something like JSONPath to get the correct object. If you don't have the full path, you do you determine, whether to update or not a certain `payload` object (ie you want to update the `payload` of the `aircraft` object but not of the `geometrical`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - retrieve value from nested object, using array of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590743/javascript-retrieve-value-from-nested-object-using-array-of-keys)

Comment: Do you need to create *new* objects, or just add that property to the existing ones?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just add the property

Comment: @derpirscher can you provide an example with JSONPAth? Your suggestion answers partially

Comment: What do you mean by "*answers partially*"? The linked duplicate provides you with a way to get the nested object from your path. Once you have the object you can apply any update you want.

Comment: @derpirscher my problem is not getting the object `{ '@_unit': 'kg' }` which has a fixed format and I can already know a priori that it will be `{ '@_unit': 'hg', '#text': 3000}`, but replace it in the right place of the JSON because it is not unique

Comment: If you know the path of the object (ie `requirements.general_info.aircraft.payload`) the linked duplicate will show you how to get that object. (eventhough I admit the path is in reverse order in that object) If you don't know the path of the object, how do you decide which of the payloads in your object to update? Because the both look exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments of T.J. Crowder and derpirscher I wrote a non-recursive function that solves the problem:

```js
const path = 'requirements.general_info.aircraft.payload';
const modifiedJsonData = updateObject(jsonData, path, 'hg', 3000);

const updateObject = (json: any, path: string, unit: string, value: number): Object => {
  const pathKeys = path.split('.');

  if (allObjectPaths(json).includes(path)) {
    let temp = json;
    pathKeys.forEach((key: string) => {
      temp = temp[key];
    });
    temp['@_unit'] = unit;
    temp['#text'] = value;
    return json;
  } else {
    throw new Error('Path is incorrect');
  }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using `lodash`.

```
import _ from 'lodash'

function updateObject(json: any, path: _.PropertyPath, unit: string, value: number) {
  if (_.has(json, path)) {
    _.setWith(json, path, { '@unit': unit, '#text': value })
  }
  return json
}

let path = 'requirements.general_info.aircraft.payload'
// alternatively:
// path = ['requirements', 'general_info', 'aircraft', 'payload']
console.dir(updateObject(json, path, 'hg', 3000), { depth:null })
```

Remember to install lodash as well as its type definitions.

```
npm -i lodash
npm -i --save-dev @types/lodash
```

Comment: Works great (we won't get rid of Lodash that easily... :D)